# Make copy/pasted text from PDF to Word spread over the entire page

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I make the text spread over the page? 
I copy/pasted text from PDF to Word, but it's not filling up the whole space (all lines). How do I make it spread over the page?

[image: table]

Comment: it looks like it's aligned "justified" wherever your cursor is. Check alignment and margins. If that fails, you have residual spaces from the pdf document and you'll need to *trim* it

Comment: Agreed, turn on paragraph marks (Ctrl+Shift+*) and the ruler and you are more likely to discover what is causing the space.

Comment: @Adam, i did it , but how do i fix it? it s simple problem ,

Comment: @Erjan, Did you identify what is causing the space? Please let us know what it is or share another screenshot and we can help further.

Comment: @Adam, thanks, it is not about identifying THE WHAT :) , it s THE HOW :) but thanks

Comment: @Adam , i fixed it , look up the answer

Comment: @Erjan, The _how_ normally comes after you know **what** exactly you are dealing with..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove paragraph pilcrows, you need to first show them by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>

Next, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to use *find and replace*

You'll want to *find* the pilcrow, but you **can't** use the ASCII code (¶ - <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>20</kbd>), you'll need to use `^p` to find the line breaks and replace them with nothing.